# Hypothesis testing in moderation analysis after Propensity Score Matching

Tags: hypothesis-testing, propensity-scores, marginal-effect

I would like to perform a moderation analysis after Propensity Score Matching with a binary outcome model. I estimate a logistic regression outcome model (following [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/estimating-effects.html#adjustments-to-the-standard-case) vignette). I am wondering, whether the hypothesis test I perform (hypothesis = "pairwise") to compare the subgroup ATTs is the correct specification when using a logistic regression model and Risk Ratios.

```
match_data_exact <- matchit (treatment ~ age +kids,  
                             data = data_psm,
                             exact =  ~ male, 
                             method = "full", distance = "glm", tol = 1e-7)


md <- match.data(match_data_exact)

fit_car <- glm(car_often ~ treatment * male , md, weights = weights, family = quasibinomial()) 

#Compute effects; RR and confidence interval
comp_car <- avg_comparisons(fit_car,
                        variables = "treatment",
                        vcov = ~subclass,
                        newdata = subset(md, treatment == 1),
                        wts = "weights",
                        comparison = "lnratioavg",
                        transform = "exp",
                        by = "male")


comp_car_hypothesis <- avg_comparisons(fit_car,
                            variables = "treatment",
                            vcov = ~subclass,
                            newdata = subset(md, treatment == 1),
                            wts = "weights",
                            comparison = "lnratioavg",
                            transform = "exp",
                            by = "male",
                            hypothesis = "pairwise")


summary(comp_car)
summary(comp_car_hypothesis)
```

```
Term              Contrast male Estimate Pr(\>|z|) 2.5 % 97.5 %. 

treatment ln(mean(1) / mean(0))    1    0.786   0.0641 0.609  1.014. 
treatment ln(mean(1) / mean(0))    0    0.729   0.0120 0.569  0.933. 

Columns: term, contrast, male, estimate, p.value, conf.low, conf.high


Term Estimate Pr(\>|z|) 2.5 % 97.5 %.  
1 - 0     1.08    0.623 0.798   1.46. 

Columns: term, estimate, p.value, conf.low, conf.high
```

Comment: First, I think some of your code is missing so you may need to amend that. Second, if this is more a coding question than an actual stats question, I think perhaps Stack Overflow is a better place.

Comment: Please edit your code. It looks like you pasted the same thing twice an are missing other parts of the code. @ShawnHemelstrand, although this seems like a coding question, I think the statistical questions is "Is `marginaleffects` performing moderation analysis correctly?" the answer to which involves knowing the statistics behind the computations done by that package. I think it's okay to be here.

Comment: That makes sense. I just wanted OP to clarify that so its clear what the intent of this question is.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand Once we get an update from OP, I'll post my answer. I'm the one who wrote the documentation they're confused about :)

Comment: Thank you for your comments so far! I edited the code, sorry for the confusion. I would like to know whether the hypothesis specification I use ("pairwise") is suitable for my model. I am interested in finding out whether the difference in the subgroup treatment effects is significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the code does is compute the log risk ratio (LRR) of the treatment for each level of the moderator (`male`). The first call (`comp_car`) displays the exponentiated LRRs, which are the risk ratios (RRs) for each level of `male`, along with the p-values for the tests that the LRRs are each equal to 0 (i.e., that the RRs are equal to 1) and the exponentiated confidence interval bounds for the LRRs (i.e., the confidence interval bounds for the RRs). All calculations are done on the LRR, but the estimate and confidence interval are exponentiated when displayed so they can be interpreted as RRs.

The second code computes the difference between the LRRs, and displays the this difference exponentiated. This is equal to the ratio of the two RRs. It displays the p-value that the difference between the LRRs is 0 (i.e., that the ratio of the RRs is 1) and the exponentiated confidence interval bounds for the LRR difference (i.e., the confidence interval bounds for the RR ratio). This correctly tests whether there is effect modification on the ratio scale by `male`. In this case, there isn't evidence for effect modification; the ratio of the RRs is close to 1 (i.e., 1.08), indicating the RRs are similar across the levels of `male`.

One small note is that the moderator should be in the propensity score model interacting with all covariates (if possible). So your model formula in `matchit()` should be `treatment ~ male * (age + kids)`. This ensures each group gets its own propensity score model rather than assuming `male` doesn't affect treatment at all. If you were able to get good balance on `age` and `kids` *within each level of `male`* then this might not be necessary. As a reviewer, I would have a problem with how you did it, especially if you didn't display balance within each level of `male`.